# Why can't I access the class in its own definition?

Tags: python, class

Why doesn't the following simple code work?

```
class A:
    a = A()

print(A.a)
```

The error I get is:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the class A is not attached to the name A in the namespace until the class definition is complete (denoted in python by a dedent). You can bind a variable to the class, however, with

```py
class A:
    pass
A.a = A()
print(A.a)
```

Because by line 3, the name A exists and points to the class, whereas it does not by line 2.

Comment: You should at least mention my name if you want to literally copy and paste my code into your answer.

Comment: I actually wrote the exact same thing first, then edited it to elaborate on my explanation. Besides, odds are very good that both of our answers are duplicates of another question on here anyway.

Comment: I see. Happens. No worries then. I did see you post an incorrect answer first and then deleted it, and then edited it after I gave my answer and then undeleted it, and that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference a class within its own definition since the class object does not actually get instantiated until its code block has been executed.

You can instead instantiate an object of the class and assign it to a class attribute of the class after the class has been defined:

```
class A:
    pass
A.a = A()
print(A.a)
```

This outputs:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x013C63B0>
```